# Why does loading a table dynamically using ajax in MVC3 only work in compatability mode?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to get a table to load dynamically using AJAX in MVC3. Why does this only work in compatibility mode in IE9? Is there a way around it?

view:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',        
        url: "/Index/GetApplicationsForUserJSON",       
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#ApplicationsForUser tbody").append("<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + data[i].Application + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data[i].Roles + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>");
            }

            $("tr:odd").css({ 'backgroundColor': '#ebf0f5' });            
        }
    });

</script>

        <table id="ApplicationsForUser" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" style="width: 99%;
            margin: 3px 0px 0px 3px">
            <thead>
                <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                    <th style="width: 45%">
                        Application
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 45%">
                        Roles
                    </th>                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

controller:

```
  public JsonResult GetApplicationsForUserJSON()
        {

            Dictionary<string, string> tableData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            tableData.Add("row1", "row1data");

            var jsonData = tableData
                          .Select(c => new
                          {
                              Application = c.Key,
                              Roles = c.Value
                          });

            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

EDIT: Pictures!

[image: Compatability Mode Off]

[image: Compatability Mode On]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a tbody element in your example. Your selector for the .append() call includes one, though. Perhaps in compatability mode, IE9 is "assuming" the presence of the tbody as the table's content.

Answer (score 0):

Because some browsers cahce data even when thay are not suppose to, some browser elements do not refresh on user request.So you have to force that by specifyng this at the controller level:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
```

This will tell the browser not to store request related data from previous requests.

Comment: didn't fix it for me...table data still doesn't display

Comment: does it give the same behaviour in firefox for example?

Comment: don't have Firefox installed but just realised that it doesnt work in Chrome either - even with the OutputCache attribute

Comment: when is your ajax method called? do you have a button for it or its hooked up to an event?

Comment: In the real app it is called on a button event but in the example I created here it is just called as is (when the page loads although I haven't put the call in document.ready) - ive tried calling it from document.ready but it still doesnt work

Comment: try to hook it up to a temporary buttons to test if the cache is really the issue. And also if you are using a button i would recommend to use @Ajax.ActionLink .