# Id is not passed to next controller from button in table row created using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a form and when i click on search button, i want the data to be displayed in the table without reloading the page. Here i'm using ajax. I managed to display the rows. Supposedly when i click on a select button in the row, the id of the chosen row will be passed to another page. But i got null error because the id value is null. I also put breakpoints to check the id value and it is null. As though the id is not passed at all.

```
$('#btnPatientSearch').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission
    $.ajax({
        url: '/consultation/GetPatientLookupList',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#frmPatientLookup').serialize(), // it will serialize the form data
        dataType: 'json',
        //})
        success: function (data) {
            $('.firstDL').remove();
            $('.subsequentDL').remove();

            var rowNo = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                rowNo += 1;
                $("#LoadPatientLookupTable tbody").append("<tr Class='odd gradeX subsequentDL'>" +
                    "<td>" + rowNo + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].paid + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].pidno + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].pidno + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].pname + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].pgender + "</td>" +
                    "<td style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;'><form Class='form-horizontal' role='form' action='@Url.Action("PatientMedicalInfo", "consultation", new { paid = Html.Raw(" + data[i].paid + ") }) method='get'><Button Class='btn btn-default' name='btnSelectPatient' id='btnSelectPatient'>Select</Button></form></td>" +
                    "</tr>");
                    //"<td>" + data[i].ToJavaScriptDate(data[i].pdob) + "</td>" +
            }
            alert('Patient list has been loaded.');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
        }
    }); // end ajax
}); // end btnPatientSearch
```

Below is the controller of PatientMedicalInfo:

```
[HttpGet()]
public ActionResult PatientMedicalInfo(string paid)
{
    PatientLookupVM Patient = new PatientLookupVM();
    dynamic CurrentPatientDetailsByPtId = Patient.GetCurrentPatientDetailsByPtId(paid);
    Patient.LoadCurrentPatientDetails = CurrentPatientDetailsByPtId;
    return View(Patient);
}
```

I also tried passing the id in the same page, but it doesn't work either. Can anyone help me please.. tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Url.Action()` is razor code and is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. Values for `data[i].paid` do not even exist at the point.

In addition, `PatientMedicalInfo()` is a GET so there is no need to generate a `form` tag, and your generating invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes in your `<button>`

You can simply generate

```
'<td><button type="button" class="select" data-id="' + data[i].paid + '">Select</button></td>'
```

and then add the following script to handle the buttons `.click()` event to redirect

```
var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("PatientMedicalInfo", "consultation")';
$("#LoadPatientLookupTable tbody").on('click', '.select', function() {
    location.href = baseUrl + '?paid=' + $(this).data('id');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. So if i want to pass other variables as well, i just add more data-someOtherName is it? Another question, will it need a different way if i want to send id to a POST method?

Comment: In that case you do either need a form (or make an ajax call if you want to stay on the same page. But your method is not a POST and its juts getting data so making it a post is not appropriate. Is there a reason you want to make a POST?

Comment: Yes, You can add as many `data-*` as you want and in the click handler, extract them and use the values to generate the url

Comment: I've read somewhere someone says that using POST is more safer for passing data.

Comment: But if there are more than 2 or 3, I would consider generating the url on the server ans passing it in the json data

Comment: Do you have some sensitive data that your concerned about being shown in the url?

Comment: About sensitive data, i'm asking just in case. By generating the url on the server and passing it in the json, do i have to do it similar way to ajax(putting json code in script)? Another question, the click handler, do i have to put it inside ajax or outside the ajax?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139211/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-nurul).